# Interact with docker container in the middle of a bash script execution [in that container]

Tags: python, bash, docker, shell, tty

I want to start a bunch of docker containers with a help of a Python script. I am using `subprocess` library for that. Essentially, I am trying to run this docker command

```py
docker = f"docker run -it --rm {env_vars} {hashes} {results} {script} {pipeline} --name {project} {CONTAINER_NAME}"
```

in a new terminal window.

```py
Popen(f'xterm -T {project} -geometry 150x30+100+350 -e {docker}', shell=True)
# or
Popen(f'xfce4-terminal -T {project} --minimize {hold} -e="{docker}"', shell=True)
```

Container's `CMD` looks like this. It's a bash script that runs other scripts and funtions in them.

```
CMD ["bash", "/run_pipeline.sh"]
```

What I am trying to do is to run an interective shell (bash) from one of these nested scripts in a specific place in case of a failure (i.e. when some condition met) to be able to investigate the problem in script, do something to fix it and continue execution (or just exit if I could not fix it).

```bash
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Investigate manually: "$REPO_NAME"
  bash
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 33; fi
fi
```

I want to do these fully automatically so I don't have to manually keep track of what is going on with a script and execute `docker attach...` when needed, because I will run multiple of such containers simultaneously.

The problem is that this "rescue" bash process exits immediately and I don't know why. I think it should be something about `tty`s and stuff, but I've tried bunch of fiddling around with it and had no success.

I tried different combinations of `-i`, `-t` and `-d` of a `docker` command, tried to use `docker attach...` right after starting container with `-d` and also tried starting python script directly from bash in a terminal (I am using Pycharm by default). Besides I tried to use `socat`, `screen`, `script` and `getty` commands (in nested bash script), but I don't know how to use them properly so it didn't end good as well. At this point I'm too confused to understand why it isn't working.

EDIT:

Adding minimal NOT reproducable (of what is not working) example of how I am starting a container.

```
# ./Dockerfile
FROM debian:bookworm-slim
SHELL ["bash", "-c"]
CMD ["bash", "/run_pipeline.sh"]

# run 'docker build -t test .'
```

```py
# ./small_example.py
from subprocess import Popen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env_vars = f"-e REPO_NAME=test -e PROJECT=test_test"
    script = f'-v "$(pwd)"/run_pipeline.sh:/run_pipeline.sh:ro'
    docker = f"docker run -it --rm {env_vars} {script} --name test_name test"

    # Popen(f'xterm -T test -geometry 150x30+100+350 +hold -e "{docker}"', shell=True).wait()
    Popen(f'xfce4-terminal -T test --hold -e="{docker}"', shell=True).wait()
```

```bash
# ./run_pipeline.sh

# do some hard work

ls non/existent/path

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Investigate manually: "$REPO_NAME"
  bash
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then exit 33; fi
fi
```

It seems like the problem can be in a `run_pipeline.sh` script, but I don't want to upload it here, it's a bigger mess than what I described earlier. But I will say anyway that I am trying to run this thing - https://github.com/IBM/D2A.

So I just wanted some advice on a `tty` stuff that I am probably missing.

Comment: too much info in the question. a [repro] please.

Comment: Is it the original `run_pipeline.sh` script you want to interact with when there's a problem? or do you want to run other scripts?  What are the xterm/xfce processes for?

Comment: @pynexj Added some example

Comment: @Matt I am not trying to interact with a script, I want to interact with a container that runs that script. I want to use xterm/xfce for just a convenient  shell window where I can instantly start doing something in case of some failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in a comment to Matt's answer, his solution in my situation does not work either. I think it's a problem with the script that I'm running. I think it's because some of the many shell processes (https://i.stack.imgur.com/av4xF.jpg) are taking up allocated tty, but I don't know for sure.

So I came up with my own workaround. I simply block an execution of the script by creating a named pipe and then reading it.

```bash
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo Investigate _make_ manually: "$REPO_NAME"
  mkfifo "/tmp/mypipe_$githash" && echo "/tmp/mypipe_$githash" && read -r res < "/tmp/mypipe_$githash"
  if [ $res -ne 0 ]; then exit 33; fi
fi
```

Then I just launch terminal emulator and execute `docker exec` in it to start a new bash process. I do it with a help of [Docker Python SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) by monitoring the output of a container so I know when to launch terminal.

```py
def monitor_container_output(container):
    line = b''
    for log in container.logs(stream=True):
        if log == b'\n':
            print(line.decode())
            if b'mypipe_' in line:
                Popen(f'xfce4-terminal -T {container.name} -e="docker exec -it {container.name} bash"', shell=True).wait()
            line = b''
            continue
        line += log


client = docker.from_env()
conatiner = client.containers.run(IMAGE_NAME, name=project, detach=True, stdin_open=True, tty=True,
                                  auto_remove=True, environment=env_vars, volumes=volumes)
monitor_container_output(container)
```

After I finish my investigation of a problem in that new bash process, I will send "status code of investigation" to tell the script to continue running or exit.

```bash
echo 0 > "/tmp/mypipe_$githash"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the initial container detached, with input and a tty.

```
docker run -dit --rm {env_vars} {script} --name test_name test
```

Monitor the container logs for the output, then attach to it.

Here is a quick script example (without a tty in this case, only because of the demo using `echo` to input)

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run --name test_name -id debian \
  bash -c 'echo start; sleep 10; echo "reading"; read var; echo "var=$var"'

while ! docker logs test_name | grep reading; do
  sleep 3
done

echo "attach input" | docker attach test_name
```

The complete output after it finishes:

```
$ docker logs test_name
start
reading
var=attach input
```

The whole process would be easier to control via the [Docker Python SDK](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) rather than having a layer of shell between the python and Docker.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about Docker Python SDK! Didn't thought about it. And a good method with monitoring container output too!

Unfortunately, this method still does not work. I think it's a problem with the script that I'm running though. I launched htop to see running processes in a container and it seems that some of the inner shell processes might take tty (because there are so many of them) ?

Look at this screenshots from htop please and tell me what do you think. https://imgur.com/a/JiPYGWd